# Получение данных Retrofit

Tags: kotlin, retrofit

Сохраняются данные в POJO? Или же я неправильно обращаюсь к POJO для извлечения данных

GetLots().photos?.get(0)?.url.toString() - если так обращаюсь, то возвращает null
А если в onResponse через response.body - response.body().photos?.get(0)?.url.toString(), то данные получаю.

```
override fun onCreate (savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration)

        textView1 = findViewById(R.id.RTextView)
        findViewById<View>(R.id.RButton1).setOnClickListener{
            textView1.text = GetLots().photos?.get(0)?.url.toString()
        }
```

```
internal fun getData() {

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        val service = retrofit.create(GetInt::class.java)
        val call = service.Beru()

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<GetLots>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<GetLots>>, response: Response<List<GetLots>>) {  
                textView1.text = response.body()?.get(0)?.photos?.get(0)?.url.toString()
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<GetLots>>, t: Throwable) {
            }
        })
    }
```

```
interface GetInt {
    @GET("lots/?method=receive&type=all")
    fun Beru(): Call<List<GetLots>>
}
```

```
data class GetLots(

    @SerializedName("photos")
    var photos: List<Photo>? = null,

    @SerializedName("_id")
    var id: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("classification")
    var classification: Classification? = null,

    @SerializedName("name")
    var name: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("catalog")
    var catalog: Catalog? = null,

    @SerializedName("count")
    var count: Int? = null,

    @SerializedName("date")
    var date: String? = null,

    @SerializedName("cost")
    var cost: Int? = null,

    @SerializedName("info")
    var info: String? = null
)
```

Comment: Где вы обращаетесь? Я что-то не вижу нигде этого кода

Comment: @danilshik Добавил

Comment: Я не понимаю, в чем у вас проблема

Comment: Когда я обращаюсь через response.body я получаю данные в textview, если же я обращаюсь к pojo классу мне выводит null. Как я понимаю либо я не сохраняю данные в Pojo либо неправильно обращаюсь.

Comment: причем тут сам класс и экземпляр класса?

Comment: вам нужно обращаться к экземплярам класса, а не к самому классу

Comment: Я думаю вы решили мою проблему, благодарю.

Comment: Вам нужно где то объявить где то var getLots: GetLots = null.
Затем в onResponse вы инициализируете переменную: getLots = response.body()?.get(0).
И затем можете использовать хоть где

Comment: Я уже начал искать сам, но благодарю вы сократили моё время. Ответьте пожалуйста на вопрос, я его помечу решенным (::